# appending select elements with options populated by php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i'm a newbie in web programming. I need to dynamically create a select element in to a form. The options of this select element was populated with php.

I have no idea how to do this. but I have this code which I cannot get to work.
I can create select tags with this but the options were not being populated.

HTML code:

```
 <div id='page3'> 
 <input type='button' id='aprod'>
 </div>
```

JS code:

```
$('#aprod').on('click',function(){
$('#page3').append('<select class="input" id="name_of_product" name="name_of_product">
<option value="">---</option> 
<?php include("config.php"); 
 $qry = $handler->prepare( "SELECT * FROM product_list WHERE plist_compid = ?");
 $qry->execute(array($id)); 
 while($row = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
 $p_id = $row["plist_id"];  
 $p_name = $row["plist_name"];  
 echo "<option value= "$p_name">$p_name</option>"; 
 }  
?>  
</select>');
});
```

Comment: Check the console if you are getting any errors?

Comment: no errors, it's just that the options for the select tags created dynamically is not populated.

Comment: why the hell are you appending ap php query with js?

Comment: so how do I do it properly?

Comment: You can't execute server side code on a client side event. You can either prepopulate the select box, keep it hidden and show on click or do an ajax on click and populate the select box.

Comment: can the clone function do this? I mean, I will create a select tag populated by php then clone and append it into the div element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the clone function I was able to accomplish this.

below is my code:

```
<div id='page3'> 
 <input type='button' id='aprod'>

 <select class="input" id="Factory_Name" name="factory">
    <option value = '' selected>---</option>

    <?php
    $qry = $handler->prepare( "SELECT * FROM factory_list WHERE flist_compid = ?");
    $qry->execute(array($id));
    while($row = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $f_id = $row['flist_id'];
        $f_name = $row['flist_name'];
        echo "<option value= '$f_name'>$f_name</option>";
    }
    ?>

</select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#aprod').on('click', function() {
    $('#Factory_Name').clone().appendTo('#page3');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A normal way to do it is:

```
<div id='page3'>
<select style="display:none;" class='input' id='name_of_product' name='name_of_product'>
          <option value=''>---</option> 
          <?php include("config.php"); 
           $qry = $handler->prepare( "SELECT * FROM product_list WHERE plist_compid = ?");
           $qry->execute(array($id)); 
           while($row = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
               $p_id = $row["plist_id"];  
               $p_name = $row["plist_name"];  
               echo '<option value= \"'.$p_name'\">'.$p_name.'</option>'; 
           }  
           ?>  
     </select> 
 <input type='button' id='aprod'>
 </div>
```

js:

```
$('#aprod').on('click',function(){
$('select input').show();
$('#aprod').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, you can't execute server side code on a client side event. And, moreover the server side code has already run & doesn't wait for your click event. You can either pre-populate the select box, keep it hidden and show on click or do an ajax on click and populate the select box. Here is the former option:

```
<div id='page3'> 
    <input type='button' id='aprod' value="Show my select box" />
    <select class="input" id="name_of_product" name="name_of_product" style="display: none;">
        <option value="">---</option>
        <?php
            include("config.php"); 
            $qry = $handler->prepare( "SELECT * FROM product_list WHERE plist_compid = ?");
            $qry->execute(array($id));
            $options = "";
            while($row = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
                $p_id = $row["plist_id"];  
                $p_name = $row["plist_name"];  
                $options .= '<option value="'.$p_name.'">'.$p_name.'</option>';
            }
            echo $options;
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

JS(jQuery):

```
$('#aprod').on('click', function() {
    $('#name_of_product').show();
});
```